# Add a border style on click along with adding item to cart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to add a border to a div that houses my product. I want it to work together with the ng-click I already have that adds the product to the cart. So, when a user clicks the 'select' button a border goes around that product letting them know they have selected it, if they click on another product it deselects the current one and selects the one clicked.

I have set it up many ways, but this is the closest I got. When the button is clicked it is putting style on all the products/divs. Any help would be awesome. I am new to Angular and this is breaking my brain.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.isSelected = false;
$scope.activeProduct = function() {
    $scope.isSelected = !$scope.isSelected;
  };
  
 });
```

```css
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.product-chooser{
    margin-right: 0;
}

 .product-chooser .product-chooser-item{
  padding: 11px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
 }

 .selected {
  border: 4px solid #D9534F;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 8px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
 }

  .product-chooser .product-chooser-item img{
   padding: 0;
  }

  .title{
   display: block;
   margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 12px;
  }

  .description{
   font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row form-group product-chooser">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div ng-class="{'selected': isSelected}" class="product-chooser-item">
                <img ng-src="{{product.product_image}}" class="img-rounded col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12" alt="">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <span class="title">{{product.product_name}}</span>
                    <span class="description">{{product.product_desc}}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProductToCart(product); activeProduct()">Select Package</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think my ng-repeat in there is messing it up, but i need it in order to pull my items from my DataBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your HTML with this

You had a **quote** for the class that you want to apply if isSelected turns true.

```
<div class="row form-group product-chooser">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div ng-class="{selected: isSelected}" class="product-chooser-item">
                <img ng-src="{{product.product_image}}" class="img-rounded col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12" alt="">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <span class="title">{{product.product_name}}</span>
                    <span class="description">{{product.product_desc}}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProductToCart(product); activeProduct()">Select Package</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I see you took out the ' ' around selected. That did not seem to work, I am getting the same result. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code,it will definitely work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.product-chooser{
    margin-right: 0;
}

 .product-chooser .product-chooser-item{
  padding: 11px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
 }

 .selected {
  border: 4px solid #D9534F;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 8px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
 }

  .product-chooser .product-chooser-item img{
   padding: 0;
  }

  .title{
   display: block;
   margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 12px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="row form-group product-chooser">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div ng-class="{selected:product.product_isSelected}" class="product-chooser-item">
                <img ng-src="{{product.product_image}}" class="img-rounded col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12" alt="">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <span class="title">{{product.product_name}}</span>
                    <span class="description">{{product.product_desc}}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProductToCart(product); activeProduct(product)">Select Package</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
(function () {
 'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.isSelected = false;
 $scope.products = [
                    {
                     product_name: "Milk Cartons",
                     product_desc: "2",
                     product_isSelected: false
                    },
                    {
                     product_name: "Donuts",
                     product_desc: "200",
                     product_isSelected: false
                    },
                    {
                     product_name: "Cookies",
                     product_desc: "300",
                     product_isSelected: false
                    },
                    {
                     product_name: "Chocolate",
                     product_desc: "5",
                     product_isSelected: false
                    },
                    {
                     product_name:"Condensed Milk Tins",
                     product_desc:"10",
                     product_isSelected: false
                    }
                  ];
   
 $scope.activeProduct = function(product) {
     product.product_isSelected = !product.product_isSelected
   };
   
  });

 })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have introduced a new parameter for the product object,which will be unique for each.
This parameter will be set to false in the beginning and the product object is passed into the function on click of the button.
each time the button is clicked the product.product_isSelected parameter will be set to the opppsite of what it is currently

Comment: I need the products to be pulled from my DataBase. I am not storing any products on my Angular controller/service. :/

Comment: You would need a specific parameter for every product object which should be set to true or false depending on the button click then it will definitely work.The reason your previous code didn't work was that the isSelected variable was checked in common for all the product objects and when it was set to true only on one button click ,all the div classes were changed

Comment: Yeah, I have a GET request, but I am not pushing them into an array, I am pushing them into an array in the cart though.

Comment: That makes sense! Okay, I will play around with it. Thank you!

Comment: will it be possible to show how your products was assigned in angular js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128502/discussion-between-stuffedpoblano-and-graveyardqueen).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use $index to get this to work.

```js
app.controller('letterCreateCtrl', function($scope, $state, letterCreateSrv, cartSrv) {
$scope.activeProduct = function(index) {
    $scope.isSelected = index;
};
});
```

```html
<div class="row form-group product-chooser">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div ng-class="{'selected-product':isSelected === $index}" class="product-chooser-item">
                <img ng-src="{{product.product_image}}" class="img-rounded col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12" alt="">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <span class="title">{{product.product_name}}</span>
                    <span class="description">{{product.product_desc}}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProductToCart(product); activeProduct($index)">Select Package</button>
```